# How to get the latest file from Hadoop file system (HDFS)?

Tags: unix, hdfs

I want to get the latest file from HDFS and was able to write something relevant with the help of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688792/get-the-last-updated-file-in-hdfs). Here is what I am trying.

```
hdfs dfs -ls /user/data/ | awk -F" " '{print $6" "$7" "$8}'|sort -nr|head|cut -d" " -f3-
```

However this method gets more than one file along with the folders too. Below is the output of execution of the above command.

```
/user/data/Filled_Elements_Reports
/user/data/Filled_Elements_Source_Reports
/user/data/sampleRandomRec_8.csv
/user/data/sampleRec_8.csv
/user/data/Rec_count_per_report_8.csv
/user/data/sampleRandomRec_208.csv
/user/data/sampleRec_208.csv
/user/data/Rec_count_per_report_208.csv
/user/data/sampleRandomRec_9.csv
/user/data/new_Rec_for_2.csv
```

I am looking to get only the below file
`/user/data/sampleRandomRec_8.csv`
And from this file I want to retrieve the number (here it is 8) after the `_` of the file.

Comment: Is `find` supported in the above command?

Comment: is `/user/data/sampleRandomRec_8.csv`  the latest modified file?

Comment: Is `hdfs dfs -ls /user/data/ | awk -F" " '{print $6" "$7" "$8}'|sort -nr|head -1 |cut -d" " -f3-` returning only a single file, note the `head` command with `-1`

Answer (score 3):

For getting latest file from HDFS using Scala code, Use below code:

val fs = FileSysteam.get(Conf)

val filestatus = fs.liststatus(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("/user/data"))

//sort the files by modification time

val sortedFiles = filestatus.sortBy(filestatus=> filestatus.getModificationTime)

//get the last file from sorted files

val last_modified_File = new Path(sortedFiles.last.getPath.toString)

This last_modified_File is the path of last created file in hdfs.